# How can I make a button move up in size (by going vertically up), but not in total size?

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a slight conflict with a button which I've been working with in **Visual Basic NET**.

My first code sample is for my **Button_Height_Tick**, which controls changing the button's height:

```
Dim ChangeHeight As Boolean = False

Private Sub Button_Height_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Height.Tick
    If Not ChangeHeight Then
        Do Until FlatButton1.Height = 63
            FlatButton1.Height += 1
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        Loop
        ChangeHeight = True
    Else

    End If
End Sub
```

And for my **FlatButton1_MouseHover**.

```
Private Sub FlatButton1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.MouseHover
    Button_Height.Enabled = True
    Button_Height.Start()
End Sub
```

Now, as you can see in the **Button_Height_Tick** sub, the code changes the height of the button to ***63***, however, when this code is ran, the buttons **total** height is changed.

Here are some photos in-case I haven't explained it well.

[What my original button looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tnyX.jpg)

[What I want it to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjeQm.jpg)

[What it's doing (going up in size vertically **going down**, when I want it to **go** ***up***)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmjuc.jpg)

*Please* comment below if you don't understand this question.

Comment: You're code is working right? but the result is different location.  I suggest is create a `variable` that stored the location of `x` and `y` of your `Button`.

Comment: Yes, all of the code works. It's not the location that's causing me the issue, it's how I want the size of the button. I'll give an example. You know how on "Gmail" or usually any other email site, when you press "Compose" that dialog comes up? Well, think of that being my button. The size increases, but the location doesn't change. @RichardBaluyut

Comment: You have to change the Location as well.  Do it all in one whack by setting the Bounds property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the 'Top' position and also I notice you have a timer then just go in a do a loop. In your example there's no need for a timer.

I'll give an example using a timer and hopefully you'll understand it and can use it for what you want. I've changed 'hover' to 'enter' and 'leave'.

If it's too slow just change the increment amount.

```
    Dim ChangeHeight As Boolean = False

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If ChangeHeight Then
        FlatButton1.Height += 2
        FlatButton1.Top -= 2
        If FlatButton1.Height < 63 Then Exit Sub
        FlatButton1.Height = 63
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    Else
        FlatButton1.Height -= 2
        FlatButton1.Top += 2
        If FlatButton1.Height > 31 Then Exit Sub
        FlatButton1.Height = 31
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FlatButton1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.MouseEnter
    ChangeHeight = True
    If Timer1.Enabled Then Exit Sub
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub FlatButton1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.MouseLeave
    ChangeHeight = False
    If Timer1.Enabled Then Exit Sub
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I did a little example of how to achieve what you are looking for.

Code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim buttonXCoordinate As Integer
Dim buttonYCoordinate As Integer
Dim buttonOriginalHeight As Integer
Dim buttonOriginalLocation As Point

Private Sub GetButtonCoordinate()
    buttonXCoordinate = testBtn.Left
    buttonYCoordinate = testBtn.Top
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    buttonOriginalHeight = testBtn.Height
    buttonOriginalLocation = testBtn.Location
    GetButtonCoordinate()
End Sub

Private Sub testBtn_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles testBtn.MouseEnter
    Dim buttonLocation As Point = Nothing
    GetButtonCoordinate()
    buttonLocation.X += buttonXCoordinate
    buttonLocation.Y += buttonYCoordinate - buttonOriginalHeight
    testBtn.Height += buttonOriginalHeight
    testBtn.Location = buttonLocation
End Sub

Private Sub testBtn_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles testBtn.MouseLeave
    testBtn.Height = buttonOriginalHeight
    testBtn.Location = buttonOriginalLocation
End Sub
End Class
```

I did it really fast but it's enough to give you an idea to how to achive your goal.

In my example there is a button called `testBtn`, when you **go over** it with the mouse it the **button's height is increased** and it **returns back** to normal **when you move your mouse out** of it

Comment: Handles exec.Click    What is that?

Comment: I added more description, i just ricreate a fast example of 2 button, one of them increase the height of the other one. Exec is the name of the button.

Comment: The OP never asked for a button that ever increases...... He wanted a button that expands when the mouse was over it. You example grows and grows.

Comment: I was pretty sure that my goal was to help him and not to do the program for him. Anyways I fixed, hope now it will be more understandable and clear.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try. Actually I agree, I would have done his (the OP) routines differently but I think it's important to stay similar to the original routines so the user can get the idea and try to improve. I agree with you completely.

Comment: I just tried your example. Great, works fine. It give the OP another option, I'll 'upvote'. Just one thing thought, don't 'Dim' variables outside of a sub or function, you should set private or public.

Comment: Thank you, Simo. I've followed @video.baba 's solution, but I'll definitely keep yours on the list as some extra tips :)

Comment: Thank you, Simo. I've followed @video.baba 's solution, but I'll definitely keep yours on the list as some extra tips :)